# JSON Result from C# not working with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, c#, chart.js

I am trying to return a json object in c# then pass it to my javscript controller.

I am hitting the c# controller, then back to the js controller but having issues formatting the chart.js chart using my json object. Do I need to use json.stringify or json.parse?

My code is below:

```
public IActionResult Get_PhasechartData(string PhaseId)
    {
        string getTempPhaseId = PhaseId;
        KT_ProjectPhasesVM vm = new KT_ProjectPhasesVM();
        var tempData1 = ProjectRepository.Get_PhasechartData()
            .Where(x => x.PhaseId.ToString() == getTempPhaseId)
            .Select(x => new {x.PhaseId, x.Effort });

        JsonResult matt = Json(tempData1);

        return matt;
    }
```

```html
$('#kt_phasechartbtn').click(function (success, fail, always) {
                    $.get('/api/project/kt_phasechart', {
                        "PhaseId": $('#kt_phaseidchart').val()
                },
                    function (mydata) {
                        var data= JSON.stringify(mydata.effort);
                        var label= JSON.stringify(mydata.phaseid);
                        var ctx = document.getElementById('phaseLineChart').getContext('2d');
                        var insightsLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                            type: 'bar',
                            data: {
                                labels: label,
                                datasets: [{
                                    data: data,
                                    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 205, 86,0.6)"
                                }]
                            }
                        });

                    }).done(success)
                    .fail(fail)
                    .always(always);
            });
```

Comment: "having issues formatting the chart.js chart using my json object" does not describe the issue. Is there an exception? Is the data ignored? Is it wrong? **You need to be specific.**

Comment: Check that the data comes from the server

Comment: I am debugging chrome, no exception but the data is coming back from the server in a json format as expected. I was able to get it working by converting json to string(json.stringify), then pushing value to array. i realize there is a JSON.parse but for some reason wasn't working.